# MySQL with JPA: Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE)

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, glassfish, collation

I need to be able to store characters like `\xF0\x9F\x94\xA5` in my database, which, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13754976/896249) need `UTF8mb4` encoding.

So I set up my database with

```
CREATE DATABASE `myDB` CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci
```

and verified in the MySQL shell if it was effective:

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM myTable;

+---------+------------------+--------------------+----
| Field   | Type             | Collation          | ...
+---------+------------------+--------------------+-----
| id      | int(10) unsigned | NULL               | ...   
| myColumn| text             | utf8mb4_general_ci | ...
+---------+------------------+--------------------+-----
```

So far so good.

After running my program, I got this **Exception**:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like'
Error Code: 1267
```

**For the record**: I am using the Java Persistency API (JPA) in my webapplication with GlassFish 3.1. The `Exception` gets thrown when executing a named query:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "myTable.findByMyColumn", query = "SELECT c FROM myTable c WHERE c.myColumn LIKE :myColumn")
```

However, it appears that the error only occurs when the queried String actually contains those weired emoji characters (`\xF0\x9F\x94\xA5`)

```
Call: SELECT id, myColumn FROM myDB.myTable WHERE myColumn LIKE ?
bind => [Something something Lorem Ipsum ]
```

So I thought, that somewhere might still be a `utf8_general_ci` set up and I tried putting the `COLLATION` directly into the query (as suggested [in this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/183624/896249))

```
@NamedQuery(name = "myTable.findByMyColumn", query = "SELECT c COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci FROM myTable c WHERE c.myColumn LIKE :myColumn")
```

But still nothing.

Then I tried putting the collation directly in the connection (in GlassFish I am using a *connection_pool*) as I [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20546571/896249)

```
characterEncoding, UTF8mb4
```

But GlassFish said only `Connection could not be allocated because: Unsupported character encoding 'UTF8mb4'`

The last thing I did was checking the Database System (I am using MariaDB)

```
show variables WHERE variable_name like "col%";
+----------------------+------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value            |
+----------------------+------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci  |
| collation_database   | utf32_general_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_general_ci  |
+----------------------+------------------+
```

And now I am completely lost...

What can I do to use `utf8mb4` or `utf-32` or anything else for that matter that is more advanced that simple UTF-8 ?

Comment: connection pool character encoding fails because in java, utf-8mb4 is just UTF-8. I think it is the connection which is not set to the right collation. Why don't you try to execute a `SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'` query during initialization of the context (or just before your `where .. like` query for testing purposes)?

Comment: Unbelievable, that little trick of yours, did the trick! The database is accepting the weired characters without complaining :) This may not be the most efficient way, but now I could just execute this: `entityManager.createNativeQuery("SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'");` whenever I expect text that needs more than utf8. Maybe you can post this an answer, so I can accept it – unless you have more good ideas

Comment: you can also set that in `my.cnf` if you prefer, but will apply to all connections (dunno if with any drawbacks)

Comment: also, can you update your jdbc client to a newer version?

Comment: This is meant to run on a remote server which I can't update myself. So all I have is a MariaDB 5.5.36 server and GlassFish 3.1.2.2. However, I won't be using the database for anything else so I can just edit `my.cnf` !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You do not need any change in the Java side, as `utf8mb4` is just `UTF-8` in Java.

Instead, as you can see here:

```
show variables WHERE variable_name like "col%";
+----------------------+------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value            |
+----------------------+------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci  |
| collation_database   | utf32_general_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_general_ci  |
+----------------------+------------------+
```

your connection setting is still `utf8_general_ci`; to set it at the connection level, one option is to execute the (mysql specific) query:

```
SET NAMES='utf8mb4'
```

before any attempt to use the utf8mb4 collation; or, generally for the mysql server, in `/etc/my.cnf`:

```
[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Another option without changing the connection string, is using a jdbc driver version >= 5.1.13:
http://www.opensubscriber.com/message/java@lists.mysql.com/14151747.html

Comment: Thank you. Interesting link - I use `mysql-connector-java-5.1.32` so I should be fine when changing the `my.conf`