# Characters like ă and ţ getting changed to ? in Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, unicode, special-characters

I am getting issue while persisting some strings with special characters, For eg:Livaković. In database it's getting saved as Livakovi?. My Jdbc string is as follows:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyDb?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci&characterSetResults=utf8&useSSL=false
```

My DB Character Set is as follows:-

[image: DB Character Set]

Mysql Version is 5.6.

I am already using useUnicode=true and characterSetResults=utf8 in jdbc connection string but still special characters are not getting correctly in DB.

below is the result of show create-

```
CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
`id` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Can anyone suggest ?

Thanks,

Comment: Why are you mixing encodings like that?

Comment: as Kayaman mentioned, you have to make sure that your character set for the database can support those characters as well. `character_set_connection` only defines how the characters are transmitted, `character_set_database` says how they are stored. Maybe the answer GUIDO gave me on a similar quesion might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26285517/896249

Comment: Try using `useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8` together. Many other answers specify them both.

Comment: Also [edit] your question to show the result from `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name`

Comment: @Kayaman didn't get you ?

Comment: @GordThompson updated the post with SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name.

Answer (score 0):

That's one of several things to check.

See [*question marks*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) , in particular

- Are the bytes to be stored encoded utf8/utf8mb4?
- Is the column in the table is CHARACTER SET utf8 (or utf8mb4).  (Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.)

More Java/JDBC notes:

Add `?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8` to the JDBC URL (you currently have `characterSetResults`)

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>

compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
<form method="post" action="/your/url/" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Comment: I have updated the post with show create table. It's using utf8.

Comment: I added some stuff.